# Chrome on Windows 8 Mouse Down/Up/Move Touch Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, windows-8, touchscreen

### This question is outdated

### The problem doesn't exist in newer versions of Chrome

I'm working on a drag-to-select jQuery plugin, which is working. The problem, is that on the touch screen, it just scrolls the page.

Chrome doesn't implement `touchstart` and other touch events, so I would assume `mousedown` would be triggered.  Here's a simplified example:

### [fullscreen demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/full/ixmLq) [ [*code*](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/ixmLq) ]

A coffeescript snippet:

```
$(document).on 'mousemove', (e) ->
  $('.follow').css
    left: e.pageX
    top: e.pageY
```

How can I get this to respond to touching the screen in Chrome on Windows 8?

Comment: Chrome does not support touch (or they suck at it :)

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot : Chrome has very good support for touch, so not quite sure why so much bitterness towards it/them :)

Comment: Is this still August 2013? A lot can change in 7 months!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the latest versions of chrome.  It's an evergreen browser, which mean nearly every user is on the current, or previous release of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got your information, and your CodePen examples are not there to check what the problem may be, but Chrome not only implements `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` etc but I have found it to have the nicest touch support of all browsers I have used in the last year.

*The only thing to ensure is that if you have two monitors, you start up the browser page on the touch screen.*

I am using Windows 8.1 with a touch-screen for JQuery plugin development (to ensure it is all tablet enabled).

### Test existence of touch with:

```
var hasTouch = (typeof TouchEvent !== "undefined");
alert(hasTouch);
```

This is some working TypeScript code straight out of one of my plugins (which works best on Chrome. IE is the problem-child for touch):

```
THIS.$element.on("touchstart", function (e)
{
    THIS.momentum.touchstart(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
});
THIS.$element.on("touchmove", function (e)
{
    THIS.momentum.touchMoveTo(e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY);
});
THIS.$element.on("touchend", function (e)
{
    THIS.momentum.touchEnd();
});
```

Comment: At the time I asked, it wasn't working on all devices.  Notice the time difference between your answer and the original question.  Windows 8.1 wasn't even out yet :-)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: It was working a year ago with Win 8 too, iPad and iPhone. Hope you got it sorted now anyway  :)